# Passing parameter in link_to without a vulnerability

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty sure this is a very noob problem, but am still scratching my head.

In a recruitment app, I have Users which **has_many** Jobs :**through** Applications.

On each Jobs#show view, I want to have a button that a user can click to go to Applications#new and create the connection between that specific job and the user.

Right now, I am using this code ->

```
<%= link_to "Apply to the Job", 
    new_application_path(:application => { :user_id => current_user.id, :job_id => @job.id }), 
    , :method => POST, :class => "button"
%>
```

But this can not work without introducing a mass assignment security flaw; a user can simply change their user id and make it seem as though someone else applied to the job.

How would I go about passing the job_id, as well as the user_id parameter in the link, while avoid mass assignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user_id is the current_user id, you can modify the route to just get the :job_id and in your controller action, use current_user id for :user_id. Then passing job_id should'nt be a problem.

```
<%= link_to "Apply to the Job", 
    new_application_path(:application => {:job_id => @job.id }), 
    , :method => POST, :class => "button"
%>
```